# Updating a column if it is null in batch

Tags: mysql, sql

Requirement - There is one table named CUSTOMER, where we need to check one column "status" value  if it is null then we need to set it to 'CLOSE' (It needs to be done as a part of bulk update everyday at one specific time). Now we may have 500/1000/100000+ records with null value in status column. But for that particular we need to update all orders.

Solution 1 - create one script having below one query,

```
Update CUSTOMER
    Set status='CLOSE'
    Where status IS NULL;
```

And schedule that to run daily at specific time.

Will this be sufficient to have in script and work properly even if on daily basis i have 500+1000+ entries in production?
Or it will cause any issue?

Solution 2 -

Or do i have to first fetch all those records with null status, store it in one array and then loop onto it and update it one by one?

Comment: 1000+  update in a good DB is something like milliseconds.

Comment: A single `update` statement is the best approach.